# Can't pick up 5 GHz Wi-Fi any more (Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter, wireless-adapter

My laptop could pick up 5 GHz before this, and it can't any more. How can I fix this?

Wi-Fi adapter: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter

Driver version: 12.0.0.720 (latest)

[Radio type support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viKwF.png)

[Device Manager Wi-Fi Adapter Advanced Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVDMZ.png)

I noticed in the Wi-Fi Adapter Advanced settings only show three options (D0 Packet Coalescing, Network Address and Roaming Aggressiveness only), and I can't see preferred band.

Comment: In Device Manager, look for Network adapters and click on it to expand its menu. From the expanded menu, look for Wireless adapter. Right click on the Wireless adapter driver, and click on Properties. A new Wireless adapter properties window will open up. Here, go to the Advanced tab. Look for 802.11n mode and select it. After selecting, change the value on the right side to Enable. Click Ok. Also the laptop could pick up 5ghz before, you could perform a system restore or roll back driver to check.

Comment: Hi @daidai, I've already tried rolling back the driver to no avail. Also there isn't the option for the bandwidths whether to change to B/G/N/AC (if you take a look at the attachedpicture (dev mgr wifi adapater advance settings)- only 3 options are available in the advance settings.

Answer (score 0):

just ran into this issue and looked for the newest driver for this device. Found the version 12.0.0.1159 and updated. Without any setup whatsoever I was instantly able to connect to 5GHz networks. Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Update to 12.0.0.916
Then you can find a "preferred band" option under Advanced tab, where you can select 5G band.